# How to call a service operation at a REST style WCF endpoint uri?

Tags: wcf, rest, endpoint

is it possible to call a service operation at a wcf endpoint uri with a self hosted service?

I want to call some default service operation when the client enters the endpoint uri of the service.

In the following sample these uris correctly call the declared operations (SayHello, SayHi):

```
- http://localhost:4711/clerk/hello
- http://localhost:4711/clerk/hi
```

But the uri

```
- http://localhost:4711/clerk
```

does not call the declared SayWelcome operation. Instead it leads to the well known 'Metadata publishing disabled' page. Enabling mex does not help, in this case the mex page is shown at the endpoint uri.

```
private void StartSampleServiceHost()
{
    ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Clerk), new Uri( "http://localhost:4711/clerk/"));
    ServiceEndpoint endpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IClerk), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
    endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
    serviceHost.Open();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IClerk
{
    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
    Stream SayWelcome();

    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/hello/")]
    Stream SayHello();

    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/hi/")]
    Stream SayHi();
}    

public class Clerk : IClerk
{
    public Stream SayWelcome() { return Say("welcome"); }

    public Stream SayHello() { return Say("hello"); }

    public Stream SayHi() { return Say("hi"); }

    private Stream Say(string what)
    {
        string page = @"<html><body>" + what + "</body></html>";
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(page));
    }
}
```

Is there any way to disable the mex handling and to enable a declared operation instead?

Thanks in advance, Dieter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try?

```
[OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/")]
Stream SayWelcome();
```

UPDATE:

Not sure why it is not working for you, I have a self hosted WCF service with the following service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDiscoveryService {

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate="")]
    Stream GetDatasets();
```

The only difference I can see is that I use WebServiceHost instead of ServiceHost.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Same result. This is consistent to the MS documentation, which states that slashes at the beginning and at the end of the uri template string are ignored.
Unfortunately it does not help.
Thank you for the suggestion, Darrel.

Comment: Darrel, thank you so much. The WebServiceHost makes the difference. When I use WebServiceHost instead of ServiceHost everything works fine!

Best Regards, Dieter